# Rails+Slim: How to use link_to tag with controller & action name; and nested content in the anchor tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

This is what I have right now:

```
li
  = link_to {:controller => "controllername", :action => "actionname"}
    span.glyphicon.sidebar-icon.glyphicon-ok-circle
    span   WhoHas
```

However this won't work as `link_to` expects it's first argument to be the content inside the anchor tag. The contents I'd like inside the anchor tag are the following `span` blocks.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said this:

> However this won't work as link_to expects it's first argument to be the content inside the anchor tag.

This is not true.  `link_to` can also accept a block instead, and it will use the content of the block instead:

```
link_to("/path/to/thing") do 
  "My link"
end
```

And, as such, does not require the first argument to be used as the text for the link.  [The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) list the following signatures:

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
  # url is a String; you can use URL helpers like
  # posts_path

link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
  # url_options, except :method, is passed to url_for

link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end

link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

The last two options are what you're looking for.

However, the real reason your code doesn't work is because you're using braces without parentheses - basically, `method { :hello => "world" }` doesn't do what you think it does.  the `method { }` syntax is reserved for blocks, so it's expecting the contents of a block - which it doesn't find.  Rather, it finds a key-value association, which is reserved for hashes.  Essentially, Ruby tries to interpret it as a block, but fails.  So your options are to either encapsulate it with parentheses, like so: `method({ :hello => "world" })`, or drop the braces, like so: `method :hello => "world"`.  You'll also need to add a `do` at the end of your `link_to` to have the content be a block, so your code looks like this now:

```
li
  = link_to :controller => "controllername", :action => "actionname" do
    span.glyphicon.sidebar-icon.glyphicon-ok-circle
    span   WhoHas
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeremy. I hadn't noticed that the link_to tag accepted a "do block" as well. I think it's worth mentioning though that the syntax you provided at the bottom didn't work as is. The arguments for the link_to tag had to be in parens for it to start working. This worked for me: 

    li
      = link_to ({:controller => "controllername", :action => "actionname"}) do
        span.glyphicon.sidebar-icon.glyphicon-ok-circle
        span   WhoHas